# How are Meta Transactions executed with OpenSea Implementation?

Tags: solidity, ether, polygon, opensea, meta-transactions

I am developing a simple ERC721 contract for Polygon with this implementation of NativeMetaTransaction (used in OpenSea code examples) https://github.com/maticnetwork/pos-portal/blob/master/contracts/common/NativeMetaTransaction.sol

What is expected from ExecuteMetaTransaction function beyond executing another function in behalf of other user? I mean, is there something OpenSea needs from this? since the function to be called can't have parameters... Or is this just boilerplate code?

Thank you in advance :)

```
    function executeMetaTransaction(
    address userAddress,
    bytes memory functionSignature,
    bytes32 sigR,
    bytes32 sigS,
    uint8 sigV
  ) public payable returns (bytes memory) {
    MetaTransaction memory metaTx = MetaTransaction({
      nonce: nonces[userAddress],
      from: userAddress,
      functionSignature: functionSignature
    });
    require(
      verify(userAddress, metaTx, sigR, sigS, sigV),
      "Signer and signature do not match"
    );

    // increase nonce for user (to avoid re-use)
    nonces[userAddress] = nonces[userAddress] + 1;

    emit MetaTransactionExecuted(
      userAddress,
      payable(msg.sender),
      functionSignature
    );

    // Append userAddress and relayer address at the end to extract it from calling context
    (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
      abi.encodePacked(functionSignature, userAddress)
    );
    require(success, "Function call not successful");

    return returnData;
  }
```

Comment: Did you find any information about this? also, do you know if Opensea run the meta-transactions only for Polygon or also for Ethereum?